# Print fuzz if seconds is multiple of 3

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It consists of creating a react component which renders time each second, if the seconds are multiple of three print "fuzz", if its multiple of 5 print "buzz" if multiple of 3 and 5 print "fuzzbuzz". I am new to react, however i tried and it seems to be the time it takes to evaluate if its a multiple a second is already past and it prints fuzz with the wrong second.

Here is the code i wrote

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Clock from 'react-clock';

class ShowDateTime extends React.Component {
  state = {
    date: new Date(),
    value: "",
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    // setInterval(
    //   () => this.setState({ date: new Date(), value:"buzz" }),
    //   1000
    // );
    setInterval(
      ()=>{

        if( this.state.date.getSeconds() % 3){
          this.setState({value: "fuzz"})
        }
        else if (this.state.date.getSeconds() % 5){
          this.setState({value: "buzz"})
        }
        else if (this.state.date.getSeconds() % 3 && this.state.date.getSeconds() % 5){
          this.setState({value: "fuzzbuzz"})
        }
        else{
          this.setState({value: ""})
        }
        this.setState({date: new Date()});
      },900
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Current time: {this.state.date.toString()}</p>
        <Clock
          value={this.state.date}
        />
        <h1>{this.state.value} : {this.state.date.getSeconds()}</h1>
      </div>

    );

}
}


ReactDOM.render(<ShowDateTime/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Think about the *order* in which you do the checks. And remember that `if ... else if ...` really is equivalent to `if ... else { if ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows incorrect time because you are not setting the date and value at the same time.

In react setState() is an asynchronous call. It won't set the state immediately, it is explained in react documentation as follows:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

Another problem is your `if`s are wrong, you should compare the modulus result to 0, ie `seconds % 3` will evaluate to true every 2 out of 3 seconds. Correct expression for your intent is `seconds % 3 == 0`(also your if else logic is wrong, once it enters a block it will skip all the others)

After fixing those, resulting code:

```
setInterval(
  () => {
    let now = new Date()
    let value = ""
    if (now.getSeconds() % 3 == 0) {
      value = "fuzz"
    }
    if (now.getSeconds() % 5 == 0) {
      value = "buzz"
    }
    if (now.getSeconds() % 15 == 0) {
      value = "fuzzbuzz"
    }

    this.setState({date: now, value: value})
  }, 900
)
```

which could be even shortened to:

```
setInterval(
  () => {
    let now = new Date()
    let value = ""
    if (now.getSeconds() % 3 == 0) {
      value += "fuzz"
    }
    if (now.getSeconds() % 5 == 0) {
      value += "buzz"
    }

    this.setState({date: now, value: value})
  }, 900
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid nested `if-then-else` constructions because that's the root cause

Additionally, the better option is not to use `else` at all, like the following:

```js
  const seconds = this.state.date.getSeconds();
  let result = '';
  if (seconds % 3) {
    result += 'fuzz';
  }
  if (seconds % 5) {
    result += 'buzz';
  }
  this.setState({
    value: result,
  })
```